# what code should I use to open a link or file in CGI perl

Tags: perl, cgi

I want to open a new link after my perl script by using cgi. Is there any function allows me to print html in my perl script?

like

```
print header(-type => "text/html" );
print start_html("Register Form");
print end_html;
```

Comment: The `print` function can print html in a Perl script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options out there, but You may use [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP/Simple.pm). Below is an example usage from [a tutorial here](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/08/20/perlandlwp.html):

my $url = 'http://freshair.npr.org/dayFA.cfm?todayDate=current';
    # Just an example: the URL for the most recent /Fresh Air/ show

```
  use LWP::Simple;
  my $content = get $url;
  die "Couldn't get $url" unless defined $content;

  # Then go do things with $content, like this:

  if($content =~ m/jazz/i) {
    print "They're talking about jazz today on Fresh Air!\n";
  } else {
    print "Fresh Air is apparently jazzless today.\n";
  }
```